# StoreKit not receiving products array

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an In-App purchase in my iOS app that allows the user to upgrade to the full version of the app. I have made a class that should handle the store. The problem is that I get an invalid ProductID error when testing the store. I have determined that the problem is not being able to get the products from the app store...

How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface PSStoreKitManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *products;


-(void)initStore;
-(void)upgradeToFull;

@end


@implementation PSStoreKitManager
@synthesize products = _products;

-(void)initStore {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        [self requestProductData];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"payments disabbled");
    }
     NSLog(@"prod id %@",kFullVersionProductId);
}

-(void)upgradeToFull {
    SKProduct *fullVersion;
    NSLog(@"no items in array products %d",[self.products count]);
    for (SKProduct *crt in self.products) {
        if ([crt.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kFullVersionProductId]) {
            fullVersion = crt;
        }
    }
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:fullVersion];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

-(void)requestProductData {
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kFullVersionProductId]];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request start];
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    self.products = response.products;
    NSLog(@"data in response: %d",[response.products count]);
}

#pragma  mark -- Transaction observer

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)

    {

        switch (transaction.transactionState)

        {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                [self failedTransaction:transaction];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

            default:

                break;

        }

    }
}

- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction

{

    // Your application should implement these two methods.

    [self recordTransaction:transaction];

    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];



    // Remove the transaction from the payment queue.

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction

{

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];

    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction

{

    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

        // Optionally, display an error here.

    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

}

-(void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kFullVersionProductId]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:kUpgradeToFullReceipt];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

}

-(void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId {
    if ([productId isEqualToString:kFullVersionProductId]) {
        NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [def setBool:YES forKey:kIsUpgradedToFull];
        [def synchronize];
    }
}



@end
```

This is in the app delegate:

```
  //set up store observer
    PSStoreKitManager *observer = [[PSStoreKitManager alloc] init];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

This is set up in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` as the store observer. It is used like this:

```
  PSStoreKitManager *store = [[PSStoreKitManager alloc] init];
            [store initStore];
            [store upgradeToFull];
```

Another question: when I registered a test user in itunnes connect it e-mailed that address and asked to confirm it by loging in with my Apple Id ... i tried that but it said "unknown apple id" ... is it a problem if this email is unconfirmed?

Comment: Is ur -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response method being called?

Comment: that is the problem ... no ... how do I make sure it is called?

Comment: do u retain your request?

Comment: and you shouldn't log your productId in your initStore: this doesn't make sense because you need to wait for the appstore answer to get ur productId

Comment: I'm using ARC ... so retain shouldn't be used right?

Comment: didREceiveResponse is definitely not getting called

Comment: define a request category with a strong qualifier if u haven't already

Comment: how exactly do I do that?

Comment: declare @property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request; in ur header file

Comment: @synthesize request   = _request;  in ur implementation

Comment: in ur requestData method just use: self.request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kFullVersionProductId]]; then

Comment: desn't work ... still crashes [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];  with 'Invalid product identifier: (null)' ... the self.products array is still empty

Comment: is didReceiveResponse now called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out ... It was caused by ARC ... the solution was to retain the store kit managing object where I was using it, otherwise it was released  faster that a response could arrive ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to test your in-app purchase in `sandbox` environment. If you have set-up a test user in iTunes connect you need to explicitly sign-out from the Apple store in your device settings. Then after launching your app when prompting if you want to log-in to allow the in-app purchase, log-in with your test user account.

Comment: I can't get there ... when I call [store initStore] it crashes with 'invalid product id' because the self.products array is empty so initWithProductIdentifier gets a null prodctId ... so I never get to see the login with test user id...